# Unresolved inclusion: <conio.h>. Why?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, header-files, conio

While running a simple c program I receive an

```
Unresolved inclusion: <conio.h>
```

What am I missing? I am using eclipse on `fedora 13`. Please help me resolve this problem. If I am missing any file or haven't installed anything let me know. Also I am new to fedora. Guide me with proper steps please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you copying code from _C_  _for_  _Dummies_ ?

Answer (score 17):

> conio.h is a C header file used in old MS-DOS compilers to create text user interfaces. It is not described in The C Programming Language book, and it is not part of the C standard library, ISO C nor is it required by POSIX.

Since you are on Linux, to resolve it don't include `conio.h` and don't use any functions from that header.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h)

Comment: Especially if you are using Fedora ;)

Comment: FWIW, most people use `conio.h` just to use `getch()` so their program doesn't exit straight away in their IDE. There's a perfectly good standard alternative in `getchar()`: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153538/2d-array-addition/3153678#3153678

Comment: @paxdiablo, +1 for enlightening me on the possible source of this ridiculous behavior.

Comment: @codaddict But i am getting the same issue for stdio.h. why? Please explain.